# Need help passing a form from HTML to PHP

Tags: php, html

So I have a html file with a select included in a form and i need to pass the selected option to a php file. Here's my HTML code:

```
<body>

Migração
<form method="post" action="GuiClient.php">
<select name="migration">
    <option value="0">Select an option</option>
    <option value="Básica">Basic</option>
    <option value="Completa">Complete</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit the form"/>
</form>
```

EDIT :

GuiClient.php code

```php
<?php

if($option == Basic){ 

  $url = "http://*/*/apiGetClientBasic.php";
  $client = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($client,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
  $response = curl_exec($client);
  echo "<br>";
  echo "<br>";
  echo $response; 

} else { 

  $url = "http://*/*/apiGetClientComplete.php";
  $client = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($client,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
  $response = curl_exec($client);
  echo "<br>";
  echo "<br>";
  echo $response;
}

  $url = "http://*/*/apiPutClient.php?data=".$response;
  $url = str_replace ( ' ', '%20', $url);
  $client = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($client,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
  $response = curl_exec($client);
  echo $response;
?>
```

I don't know how to pass the selected option to GuiClient in order to use the right method

Comment: Where is the GuiClient.php code?

Comment: When submit is clicked then it will be passed to GuiClient.php, provided that the rest of your HTML is there (html, head, closing body etc.) what's the problem?

Comment: I don't know how to pass the selected option to GuiClient in order to use the right method

Comment: `$option == $_POST['migration']`

Answer (score 0):

$migration== $_POST['migration'];

this will assign the value which u entered from html to the php page.

use  in your GuiClient.php code to see if you are getting the value.

after that you can proceed along with your work